# django Markdown problems

Tags: django, markdown

Django:1.11.5

Python:3.5.2

Markdown 2.6.9 https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Markdown/

#### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post
import markdown
def home(request):
    Post_list = Post.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')
    Post.content = markdown.markdown(Post.content)
    return render(request, 'home.html',
                  context={'Post_list':Post_list})

# Create your views here.
```

#### models.py

```
from django.db import models
import django.utils.timezone as timezone
class Category(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    content = models.TextField(blank = True, null = True)

    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    update_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)


# Create your models here.
```

#### Error message

```
AttributeError at /
'DeferredAttribute' object has no attribute 'strip'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://www.balinzuoqi.com/
Django Version: 1.11.5
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'DeferredAttribute' object has no attribute 'strip'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/markdown/__init__.py in convert, line 355
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.5.2
Python Path:    
['/data/mysite',
 '/usr/local/bin',
 '/usr/lib/python35.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-i386-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

Do not know where there is a problem.

Remove Post.content = markdown.markdown (Post.content), show normal!

English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.

Comment: Few problems in your question 1. You haven't added complete error log. 2. You have not mentioned which markdown package you are using. There are lots of markdown packages for Python and Django.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt! It has been modified!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading `content` from and writing `content` to the `Post` class, not an instance of the class. You need to iterate through the list and update each instance:

```
def home(request):
    Post_list = Post.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')
    for post in Post_list:
        post.content = markdown.markdown(post.content)
    return render(request, 'home.html',
                  context={'Post_list':Post_list})
```

Whether that is a recommended way of converting Markdown to HTML to pass to a template is another matter. Its been a few years since I've used Django, but that wasn't how it used to be done. However, that is a different question.

Regardless, you were not actually passing any Markdown text to the Markdown parser as you were not using an instance of the class. With the for loop I added above, the Markdown content for each 'Post' is now being passed to the Markdown parser.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this question, troubled me one day. Really thank you! good luck!English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.